# Declaring early bound MSXML object throws an error in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, scripting, msxml

I am trying to import xml data into excel..
So the first line of the code is

`Dim XMLDOC As MSXML2.DOMDocument`

and this gives an error "user defined type not defined"

Comment: In addition to what [Scott](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11245915/190829) suggested, you could `Dim ... As Object` and avoid the early binding issue.

Comment: Please mark the Scott Holtzman's answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 51):

Inside the VBE, Go to Tools -> References, then Select Microsoft XML, v6.0 (or whatever your latest is. This will give you access to the XML Object Library.

Updated with fancy pic!

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me mad. And the fancy pic seals the deal.

Comment: damn still using windows xp :|

Comment: As a side note, if you are on Windows 8, you may need to reference Microsoft XML v3 because v6 does not expose DOMDocument class. See thread http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f9180e5c-7c2f-44be-8415-d0d2b76e3f7f/microsoft-xml-v60-msxml6dll-and-vba

Comment: As a side note to the side note from @marcel-gosselin, you can still use v6 if you `dim` your variable as `MSXML2.DOMDocument60` (note the 60 at the end)

Comment: Nice find @MarcelGosselin.  Also solves my problem on Windows Server 2012.

Comment: wait - no freehand red circles? ;P

Answer (score 38):

I had `DOMDocument` defined which needed `Microsoft XML, v3.0` but I had `Microsoft XML, v6.0` selected in references which caused the below error

> "user defined type not defined".

**The solution**

The solution was to either change `DOMDocument` to `DOMDocument60` (60 uses ver 6.0) or use the `Microsoft XML, v3.0` reference with `DomDocument`.

---

Just a quick note, if anyone is using a different version, such as Microsoft XML, v4.0, then `DOMDocument40` should be used. This is because the number at the end of the `DOMDocument` is specific to the version of the library being used.

Comment: I found that anytime users had to reboot excel, if `DOMDocument` is used in Windows10, the MS XML, v3.0 selected would go back to v6.0. The better route is to use `DOMDocument60` IMHO.

Comment: Version 6.0 is the latest version, 3.0 the last stable version (loaded by default if no version number indicated); vers. 4.0 definitively cannot be recommended anymore in current applications.

Answer (score 4):

I work with a VBA Excel Macro that someone else wrote and I was tasked with fixing it after recently upgrading from Windows 7 / Office 2010 to Windows 10 / Office 2016. I started to receive the same "user defined type not defined" compile error. My previous install also had MS XML v6.0 but apparently you have to specifically point to this version in your code on Windows 10 and/or Office 2016 (I wasn't able to confirm which upgrade caused the issue). I was able to resolve the issue by doing a Find/Replace on the following:

```
"DOMDocument" to "MSXML2.DOMDocument60"
"XMLHTTP" to "MSXML2.XMLHTTP60"
```

Answer (score 4):

I am using Microsoft Windows 10 & Office 2016.

Using **Microsoft XML 6.0** does not fix the problem.

Selecting  **Microsoft XML 3.0** fixed the compilation error

[image: Microsoft XML 3.0 reference]

Comment: I had a unique situation where my program correctly parsed the XML from one URL and failed when extracting from another (completely different) URL when using version 6. Reversing to version 3 made it work with both URLs. I changed all instances of  `DOMDocument60` to `DOMDocument30`. I closed and reopened Excel and did not have the issue described above where the reference reverts to version 6. (Using W10 and Office 2016).

Answer (score 0):

I had the 3rd and 6th versions installed, and the project uses the 4th one. I installed the 4th version from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15697 and this solved the problem.